# Compare a parameter value returned in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json.net

The code return data in JSON format and it contains around ten values, one of the value called state. I want to create function to compare a returned value of state only, for example if state = one show image1 and if state = 2 show image2. How to do that?

JQuery url

```
var RealDataApi = function () {
var url_getgatedata = "api/realdata/getgatedata";

// public functions
return {
    getGateData: function (done, fail, always) {
        var jqxhr = $.get(url_getgatedata);
        jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always);
    },
```

JSON Data:

```
{"gateNo":1,"fullOpen":false,"fullClose":false,"opening":false,"closing":false,"mode":null,"state":null,"cond":null,"positionM":null,"positionP":null}
```

Comment: the returned data doesn't look like in JSON format

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fzs78w8c/2/)

```
getParameterByName(data);//get parameter name state


function getParameterByName(data) {
    if (data.state == '2') {
        alert('2');
    } else {
        alert(data.state);
    }
}
```

Named the json data then you can get the value of state like `data.state` then compare it to which ever value you want to compare

Comment: how to get parameter by name from url ?

Comment: that is a completely different question i guess?can you explain more?

Comment: still the same question. as you can see, data is returned via this `var RealDataApi = function () {
var url_getgatedata = "api/realdata/getgatedata";

// public functions
return {
    getGateData: function (done, fail, always) {
        var jqxhr = $.get(url_getgatedata);
        jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always);
    },` these returned value has state as shown in JSON data, I want to compare state value and do something, for example show state value.

Comment: like that you run the function and putting the parameter data into the function and the function will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
if (jqxhr.state == 1) {
    //Do whatever you wanna do...
} else if (jqxhr.state == 2) {
    //Do whatever you wanna do...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use eval on a json response:

```
function getState(data)
{
    if(data.state==1)
        return "image1";
    else if(data.state==2)
        return "image2";
} 

var jqxhr=eval({"gateNo":1,"fullOpen":false,"fullClose":false,"opening":false,"closing":false,"mode":null,"state":1,"cond":null,"positionM":null,"positionP":null});//parse as js object or eval($.get(url_getgatedata));
alert(getState(jqxhr));
```

Comment: I would like to make it as a function, due to some other requirement, how to do it as a function?

Comment: Ok changed it to function just pass the data to it